# Brew Installing pygame error (OSX Mavericks)

Tags: python, macos, pygame, homebrew

I have been following instructions on how to install pygame on a mac. Here is the link to the website where the instructions are: http://dudeslife.com/blog/2014/programming/installing-python-3-3-3-pygame-on-os-x-mavericks/

I am on the last step and when I put "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.3.3/bin/pip3 
install /Users/BEASTMACHINEjr/Downloads/pygame" into terminal, this error occurs:

"/Users/BEASTMACHIENEjr/Downloads/pygame
-bash: /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.3.3/bin/pip3: No such file or directory"

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Also, I am new to osx, if anyone has an answer please simplify it. ;)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like something is not where you say it is.

Try the command  "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1/bin/pip3 install Users/BEASTMACHINEjr/Downloads/pygame"

Explanation:
Pip3 is the command that will be doing the installation and /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.3.3/bin/ is the location of where you are saying it is at. If you downloaded python3 recently then it will be version 3.4.1 so the path you should use is /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1/bin/pip3. The website says to use the 3.3.3 because that was the newest version when they made the page.

Comment: I tried that, no errors happened, however there wasn't anything showing up either. When I tried a pygame file, it still had "no module named pygame"

Comment: What was the command that you used to launch the game? I think you will need to use the command python3 and not just python.

Comment: You mean import pygame?

Comment: No, what I meant is that there are multiple versions of the python interpreter on your computer. It looks like pygame installed to Python3 and the default version on a mac is Python 2.7. When you try to execute a program on the command line, once you are in the files directory, you most likely typed "python myPygameFile.py" when you needed to type "python3 myPygameFile.py".

Comment: "File "/Users/BEASTMACHIENEjr/Desktop/Main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame
ImportError: No module named 'pygame'"

Comment: What happens when you do the command "which python3" it should print out the homebrew installation of python3. If it does then launch the interpreter with out a file name (ie the command "python3") and you will get the prompt ">>>" type in "import pygame" hopefully that will succeed meaning pygame was successfully installed.

Comment: When I did that I didn't get any errors. But still "no module named pygame".

Comment: Can you attach the python file and a screen shot of the terminal window?